# Как получить из набора чисел и перебора разных операций между ними заданное число или близкое к нему?

Tags: python, python-3.x, комбинаторика

**Задача:**

Есть набор чисел, которые каким то образом должны приводить к определенному результату. Предполагаю, что ни одна цифра не может быть уменьшена. И результат зависит от каждого числа

Набор чисел:  `[3725, 990, 7, 1, 3275, 7, 990, 3, 1, 1]`

**Думаю, из условия задачи можно утверждать следующее:**

Нужно найти такую комбинацию математических операций (умножение и сложение) между этими элементами, в любой последовательности, чтобы в итоге получилось значение максимально близкое к числу `1432` (например мы указываем разброс). При этом каждое число может быть умножено на коэффициент от 1% до 200%.
Вывод программы это те комбинации, в результате которых получилось число `1432` с указанным разбросом.

Например:

`3725*(от 0.01 до 2) + 990* (от 0.01 до 2) + 7* (от 0.01 до 2)`

Кодом

```
import itertools


l1 = [3725, 0, 990, 7, 1, 3275, 7, 990, 3, True, True]

for perm in itertools.permutations(l1, 10):
    print(perm)
```

Получилось сделать все существующие перестановки. Также с помощью `eval()` можно считать что выдает такая то комбинация (мб есть способ лучше). Мог подойти метод `join`, для подстановки операций, но, учитывая, что операции не одинаковые между элементами, то нетю Также от перестановки мест слагаемых сумма не меняется, так что вероятно (если я не туплю) это тоже можно учесть.

Учитывая невообразимое количество возможных комбинаций чисел и операций, то нужно сделать оптимизированный код.

Как это можно реализовать или в каком направлении смотреть и какие библиотеки использовать для задачи?

P.S. Это не задачка из учебника, а попытка решить свою собственную.

P.P.S. за счет [этих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1329276/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B) получилось реализовать необходимый код

```
from itertools import product


c = [x * 0.01 for x in range(1, 201)]
c = [str(i) for i in c]
points = [3725, 990, 7, 1, 3275, 7, 990, 3, 1, 1]
points = [str(i) for i in points]
for operation in product("*+", repeat=10):
    for coefficient in product(c, repeat=10):
        s = ""
        for q, w, e in zip(points, list(operation), coefficient):
            s += f"{q}{w}{e}"
        out = eval(s)
        if 1400 < out < 1500:
            print(s,"|",out)
```

Теперь вопрос только в том, как его оптимизировать.

Comment: Умножать только на целое число процентов? При чём тут вообще перестановки и что за код в вопросе?

Comment: @Qwertiy На целое

Я не знал как описать задачу и решил, что если нужно любым способом из этих чисел получить нужное, то придется использовать перестановки, код перестановок я и написал.

Answer (score 2):

C моей точки зрения данная постановка задачи - это задача полного перебора.
Единственно, что можно сделать -  ограничить этот перебор, но тогда надо явно ограничить точность вычисления. Допустим я ее приму 0.1. А также - в соответствии с вашим примером - вы допускаете только операции сложения между числами из вашего множества, умноженными на коэффициент от 0.01 до 2.0.

Берем ПРОИЗВОЛЬНОЕ число из набора, **лежащее в диапазоне от [x/2,x/0.01] где х целевое число (в данном примере 1432).** (Таким образом ваш перебор становиться целенаправленным и из него в вашем примере на данном шаге удаляются все 1,3,7). Ну например берем 990. Подбираем коэффициент: 990*1.44=1425.6. Определяем разность 1432-1425.6=6.4

Повторяем вышеописанное действие взяв другое число. В вашем случае это может быть только 7. Только оно лежит в диапазоне от 6.4/2 до 6.4*100

Для 7 имеем = 7*0.91=6.73.  1432-1425.6-6.37 = 0.03 Точность  меньше принятой выше (0.1) т.е. эти значения можно считать решением. Если же точность не достигнута - пытаемся выбрать следующее подходящее число и повторяем описанную процедуру для остатка.

Таким образом, количество комбинаций существенно сокращается.

Но если вы еще и допускаете умножения и сложения ДО операции умножения на коэффициент, то это  - перебор всех возможных комбинаций и поиск ближайшего к заданному результату -  становиться чистой задачей перебора, решить которую за осмысленное время в общем случае невозможно.

P.S. Только вот я не могу придумать реальную задачу, которая свелась бы к вашей постановке. А следовательно - это скорее всего какое-то умозрительное построение, программировать решение которого можно только из большой любви к абстрактному искусству.

Comment: Уфф, ну то что вы написали читать и перечитывать и перечитывать. Благодарю за пищу, нужно ее переварить.

Задача донельзя реальная, по итогам одной игры тебе дается определенное количество баллов, и сказано, что эти баллы зависят от определенных действий: сколько убил, сколько вылечил и т.д. 
У меня есть все эти значения (сколько убил и т.д.), и все они положительные, так что вычитаться не могут. 

Так что задача разгадать формулу подсчета очков.

Comment: Разгадать формулу по одному экземпляру данных  невозможно. А вот если у вас будет много таких примеров - то вполне. Методы ;для решения -  искать в Статистике и Machine Learning

Answer (score 0):

Если рассматривать только линейные комбинации входных чисел (а именно это ваш код делает, правда довольно много ненужных вариантов при этом генерирует), то эту задачy легко можно переформулировать как задачу [линейного программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и для нее есть эффективные [методы решения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Вот есть у вас набор чисел `[a1, a2, ..., an]` и желаемый результат `R`. Нужно найти такие `x1, x2, ... , xn` и `y` чтобы минимизировать `y` (это разница между суммой и желаемым результатом) при условиях:

```
a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + ... + an * xn - R = y
0.01 <= xi <= 2, для всех i
0 <= y
```

А это классическая задача линейного программирования. Решив ее найдете нужные вам коэффициенты `xi`.

Так же сюда можно легко добавить еще ограничений, т.е. если у вас не один набор известных `a1,...,an` и `R`, а результат известен для нескольких таких наборов. Тогда будет несколько уравнений типа `ai1 * x1 + ai2 * x2 + ... + ain * xn - Ri = yi` и минимизировать нужно будет `y1 + y2 + .. yk`.