# Как упростить вложенные циклы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, комбинаторика

```
l1 = ("*","+")

for i1 in l1:
    for i2 in l1:
        for i3 in l1:
            for i4 in l1:
                for i5 in l1:
                    for i6 in l1:
                        for i7 in l1:
                            for i8 in l1:
                                for i9 in l1:
                                    for i10 in l1:
                                        print([i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10])
```

Как оставить тот же вывод, но сделать код человеческим?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
from itertools import product

for row in product("*+", repeat=10):
    print(list(row))
```

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/ReaVWQ

```
chs = ("*", "+")

for i in range(1024):
  print([chs[(i >> x) & 1] for x in range(10)])
```

Comment: @Cowboyserg, зато работать должно быстрее :)

Comment: `print([chs[(i >> x) & 1] for x in range(10)][::-1])` ?

Comment: @S.Nick, зачем переворачивать?

Comment: Как оставить тот же вывод ...

Comment: @S.Nick, ну, последний цикл меняется раньше, как и у меня последний бит.

Comment: @Qwertiy не, я замерил на 100 запусках и того и того. У вас 6.3782271 сек, а с итертулсами 6.125458))

Comment: @Cowboyserg, да, похоже, я неправ и product работает быстрее: https://ideone.com/0eC8iv. Ну либо руки кривые и я измерять не умею...

Answer (score 1):

```
bits = 10
trans_rule = str.maketrans({'0': '*', '1': '+'})
for i in range(len(trans_rule) ** bits):
    print(list(f'{i:0{bits}b}'.translate(trans_rule)))
```

Comment: `f'{i:0{bits}b}'`

Comment: @extrn Ok! Избавляемся от магии!